# httplib could not establish connection

Tags: c++, client, httplib

I'm working on C++ software that has to communicate with an API via REST API. I'm using httplib. I do the next:

```
httplib::SSLClient cli("https://www.google.com");
httplib::Result res = cli.Get("/doodles");
if (res && res->status == 200)
{
    std::cout << res->body << "\n";
}
else
{
    auto err = res.error();
    std::cout << httplib::to_string(err) << "\n";
}
```

It responds with this error message: `Could not establish connection`
If I type the given URL into the browser, it corresponds correctly.
I tried to give the port number (443) into the constructor of the `SSLClient`, but I don't have any different results.
I have OpenSSL on my PC, and I included the httplib like this:

```
#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
#include <httplib\httplib.h>
```

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try connecting to the service in a different way (using your browser for instance). That will tell you if the problem is your program, or if it is some connection problem that has nothing to do with your program.

Comment: The constructor is `inline SSLClient::SSLClient(const std::string &host)`, so I guess it wants the host without `https://` just `"www.google.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can only work with `host` part when parsing URLs.
I had the same issue with MinGW64 (gcc 13 & cpp-httplib 0.12.6).

If you only need the `host` part of a URL, you can use spec-compliant libraries such as the [ada](https://github.com/ada-url/ada) libraries.

The following code is able to successfully download the homepage of "google.com" and write it to a file.

compile command (Windows, MinGW64):
`g++ x1.cpp -I. -static -lcrypt32 -lwinmm -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32`

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
#include <fstream>
#include <httplib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool downloadFile(const std::string &url, const std::string &path) {
  httplib::SSLClient client{url};
  client.enable_server_certificate_verification(false);

  std::ofstream file(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
  if (!file) { return false; }

  auto response =
      client.Get("/", [&](const char *data, size_t data_length) -> bool {
        file.write(data, data_length);
        return true;
      });

  return response;
}

int main() {
  std::string url = "www.google.com";
  std::string path = "downloaded_file.txt";

  if (downloadFile(url, path)) {
    std::cout << "File downloaded successfully." << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Failed to download the file." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```