# httplib can't establish connection when authorization is needed (c++)

Tags: c++, rest, http, client

I am currently trying to use httplib in C++ to make use of REST APIs.
Currently I'm trying to access a REST API that requires Authorisation with a X-Auth-Token.
However when trying to do this I always get the error message:
"Could not establish connection (2)"

I tried using the URL in the browser and while it wants me to log in, the URL seems to exist.
Testing with a different REST API that doesn't need authentification it worked just fine.
Also using other Programming languages to make the same request I'm trying to do in C++ works fine.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<httplib.h>
int main(){/*
    //Working example
    httplib::Client cl2("http://rest.ensembl.org");
    //(Not a real API-Token)
    httplib::Headers headers2={{"Content-Type","application/json"}};
    auto res2=cl2.Get("/sequence/region/human/5:1000:20000:1",headers2);
    std::cout<<"Test 1\n"<<res2->body<<std::endl;*/

    //Not working example
    httplib::Client cl("http://na-west-1.cloud.dwavesys.com/sapi/v2");
    //(I used a real API token for my tests)
    httplib::Headers headers={{"X-Auth-Token","ABC-23456789012345678901234567890"}};
    auto res=cl.Get("/solvers/remote/Advantage_system4.1/?filter=properties.qubits",headers);
    std::cout<<"Test 2\n"<<res.error()<<std::endl;
}
```

The first (but commented out) example works as it should however the second one gives me the error.
I also couldn't finde a possibility to test if I can access this REST API in the first place as there isn't a single API call I'm aware of that doesn't need a token.
I also looked at [httplib could not establish connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090048/httplib-could-not-establish-connection)
and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: It might mean more literally it can't connect to that HTTP (??) service. I'd expect HTTPS in 2023, so that might be your issue.

Comment: The issue arises with both using https and http. In both cases the first API works and the second won't.

Comment: A) Can you be more specific as to which endpoint works? B) Are you sure that host is accepting connections on port 443 (HTTPS)?

Comment: From the REST API I try to use (the dwavesys one) the issue arises with every endpoint. The first example works fine and deliveres the desired results. About the second one I'm not that good with html in general however using the very same url and the very same headers in other programing languages like python and java it works fine so I assume it would work.

Comment: No idea how HTML factors in here.

Comment: That was a typo I meant html.

Comment: "HTML", again, meaning "HTTP"?

Comment: Yes I meant http.